# Dialog box conflict with an other script

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a problem to integrate a Jquery UI dialog box in an other script. What i want to do is to detect user inactivity and after a certain inactivity time showed a dialog box to ask to continue or close session. My code :

```
    <link href="css/smoothness/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="js/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

<div id="dialog-confirm" title="Session expirée">
<p><span style="float:left; margin:0 0px 0px 0;"></span>Session expire, continue ?</p>
</div>

<script>

    var theTime;

    document.onmousemove=stockTime;
    function stockTime() {
        currentTime=new Date();
        theTime=currentTime.getTime();
    }
    function verifTime() {
        currentTime=new Date();
        var timeNow=currentTime.getTime();
        if (timeNow-theTime>10000) {

            $( "#dialog-confirm" ).dialog({
                resizable: false,
                height:190,
                modal: true,
                buttons: {
                "Continue": function() {
                $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                },
                "End": function() {
                $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                }
                }
            });      
        }
    }
    window.setInterval("verifTime()",2500);

</script>
```

My console send me that message : " TypeError: $(...).dialog is not a function ". I have no idea of where is the problem ...

Thanks for your help, and sorry for my bad english !

Comment: Seems like you don't have jQuery/jQuery UI loaded.

Comment: Make sure you have included these two files - <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

Comment: I thought about that too, but when I only use the pop up it's working properly

Comment: http://jsbin.com/zuvad/1/edit your code is working fine.. its just issue with jquery-ui / jquery

Comment: Sounds like jQuery UI not loaded correctly (wrong path) or your custom build doesn't implement dialog() method. So instead, try including jQuery UI from a CDN and if it works, build a jQuery UI including the dialog

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if all files are loaded in proper order

```
<link href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

Your remaining code is working fine.

[**Tested in JSBIN**](http://jsbin.com/zuvad/1/edit)

Comment: I have edit my question. Yes i have laoded those files

Comment: @user3631510 Still try it at least: `http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js` (or which version you want) should fix your issue

Comment: I have your exact version of jquery and query-ui http://jsbin.com/bomis/2/edit its working fine @user3631510 i guess your relative path of the files is not proper.. try loading using CDN urls

Comment: I made the change is nothing works, there is still a conflict and mydialog function is not loaded :/

Comment: Just to make sure, as per your code you need to be in inactive mode for 10sec and if you are making mouse movements in between the page dialog may not come ;)

Comment: It works ! One of my script was called twice .... Shame on me ! Thanks for all your replies !

Answer (score 0):

where u added jquery? If u haven't added it, added it above it your script, and if you added it, then I think you added it below your script, move your script after jquery. and after doing this, load your script after dom loads as

```
$(function(){
//Put your Script here
})
```

Comment: try  $(function(){window.setInterval("verifTime()",2500);})